# OPENLDAP: how to set attributes as required?

Tags: openldap, attributes

I installed `OPENLDAP 2.4.44` on `CentOS 7`.

Now I need to set any attributes as required, is it possible?
I need that all users have this attributes required:

```
- givenName
- sn
- cn
- userPassword
- displayName
- o
```

How Can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> I need that all users have this attributes required:
>
> givenName, sn, cn, userPassword, displayName, o

The relevant information in the subschema is the object class definition (see [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-4.1.1)). So the first question is which object classes you're using for the entries.

First of all: Don't muck with any standard object class definitions!

Furthermore learn about structural vs. auxiliary object classes.

Basically you have two options:

1. Define your own custom object class(es) derived from standard object classes and adding attributes in *MUST* declaration as needed.
2. Add a [DIT content rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-4.1.6) for the structural object class with *MUST* declaration as needed. DIT content rules also have *AUX* to define the auxiliary object classes usable along with this structural object class, and *MAY* and *NOT* to define the optional attributes.

The first solution is most times better because most schema-aware LDAP clients do not understand DIT content rules. Personally I often use a combination of both, especially with *NOT* in DIT content rules to exclude attributes which should never be added.

As a more complex example you can have a look at how schema is defined for [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com) using OpenLDAP static config method (aka *slapd.conf*):

- [Graphs of Æ-DIR object class and attribute type hierarchy](https://www.ae-dir.com/docs.html#schema)
- [OpenLDAP schema file ae-dir.schema](https://gitlab.com/ae-dir/ansible-ae-dir-server/blob/master/files/schema/ae-dir.schema) (uses some more [OID macros](https://gitlab.com/ae-dir/ansible-ae-dir-server/blob/master/files/schema/stroeder.com-oid-macros.schema))

Answer (score -1):

thank you so much for your reply.

Could you sent me the example or the guide (step-to-step) link? 
My skill on OpenLDAP are not strong.

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Do not add a comment as an answer. Use the link "add a comment" beneath the answer instead.